# Is there a way to lowercase all subdirectory names using bash script?

Tags: linux, bash, file-management

I'm trying to format old files to fit/incorporate in our current automation of dataset processing. However, the directory and sub-directory names of the old files where all in upper case.

I don't exactly know how to do this using bash script. Is there a way to change all directory and sub-directory names to lower case?

Comment: Do you want to rename files too, or just directories? eg. Should `DIR2/DIR3/FILE4` become `dir2/dir3/FILE4` or `dir2/dir3/file4` ?

Comment: Do you care about non-ASCII characters in names? eg. Should `ABCÄÜÏÖËŸ` become `abcäüïöëÿ` ?

Comment: If directories `AAA`, `AaA` and `aAa` exist, what should happen?

Comment: @jhnc i just need to rename the directories. the filenames are fine. there are no non-ASCII names and if it's mixed case, i need it to be just lowercase.

Comment: So `AAA` becomaes `aaa` and `AaA` becomes the same `aaa` and `aAa` becomes the same `aaa`. Does that mean you want the contents of all three to be merged together?

Comment: Also consider `DDD/file` and `DdD/file`. If both `DDD/` and `DdD/` merge to become a single new `ddd/`, then there will be two `ddd/file`. What should happen to the extra?

Answer (score 3):

If you want to change the directories and subdirectories only (i.e. leave the files alone), you should go with the `find` command.

If you are using bash v. 4 or greater you can do it without invoking any other program but bash itself:

```bash
$ find . -mindepth 1 -depth -type d -execdir bash -c \
    'mv -T "${0}" "${0,,}"' "{}" \;
```

(edited to add the `-T` option, see comments).

Otherwise, you need to convert the directory name by other means, e.g. `tr`:

```bash
$ find . -mindepth 1 -depth -type d -execdir bash -c \
    'mv -T "$0" "$(echo $0 | tr [:upper:] [:lower:])"' "{}" \;
```

(edited to add double quotes around paths, as suggested in the comments)

Note that you **must** use `-depth` in order to change the directory names in *depth-first* order (do not cut the branch you are sitting on).

Also, you need `-execdir` instead of `-exec` to rename just one path element at a time.

Comment: With your second command, you forgot to doublequote `$0` and `$ln` usage. Consider a directory named `A B   C`

Comment: Note that if you have two directories, `AAA` and `AAa`, this code will move one of them  to `aaa` and the other inside it (either `aaa/AAA` or `aaa/AAa`)

Comment: Absolutely correct. I assumed, as the OP stated, that the names "were all in upper case". To cope with all the general cases a script would fit better than a one-liner.

Comment: Still, you can make it more robust by using the `-T` option of `bash`'s `mv` command (treat DEST as a normal file). I just found out about it thanks to your comment.

Comment: You missed a `$0` and single-quotes can't be nested. `-T` isn't portable (I can only find it in the coreutils version of `mv`) but when available could be very useful, nice find. (It's not part of bash, btw)

Comment: Does the `echo $0` really need quotes? I have them around the whole subcommand, it should be enough. The single quotes are actually a mistake, but they don't harm because `tr` don't need them. I'll remove them for clarity anyway.
For the `-T` you are right, I was assuming that `mv` was a built-in command, but that's not the case...

Comment: `echo $0` compacts characters in `$IFS`. eg. `A B   C` will be renamed to `a b c`. Also, in general, not quoting `tr` arguments could cause subtle bugs. eg. try `mkdir 'A B   C' w` and then run your second command

Answer (score 2):

This may come handy:

```
$ var=AAA
$ echo ${var,}
aAA
$ echo ${var,,}
aaa
```

And to upper:

```
$ var=aaa
$ echo ${var^}
Aaa
$ echo ${var^^}
AAA
```

Answer (score 0):

`tr` may be of help, as in

```
echo HELLO | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]'
```

So you may do something similar to

```
for i in $(ls)
do
  mv $i $(echo $i | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]')
done
```

Comment: Parsing output of `ls` is bad practice. The `for` will fail if directory names contain any character in `$IFS` (eg. space). It is good practice to quote variables (eg. `"$i"`)

Answer (score 0):

## A pure Bash find based concept

Based on [Knut's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75139008/8296094) I would propose you to extend to the snippet below and build upn:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -exec echo echo {} \| tr "[:upper:]" "[:lower:]" \;

find . -maxdepth 1 -exec echo mv {} \$\(echo {} \| tr "[:upper:]" "[:lower:]"\) \;
```

This is going to build and show you the operations needed to create the lower case named folders. You could use the output as a template for your renaming script, or wrap it in a renaming function for instance.

[image]

### Variations of the same command for higher flexibility:

- **find .**: the period is going to search in the local directory you are in. If you'd like to analyse another folder, just replace the dot with the path to that folder. Example: *$ find /path/to/another*
- **-maxdepth 1**: This is the depth the find command should take into consideration. 1 means, apply only on the subfolders of this folder (recursion level 1). *-maxdepth 2* means, go into every subfolder and do the same (recursion level 2). ...

Comment: consider a directory called `A B'     "C`